# How to add a border outside of element with ::before selector?

Tags: html, css

[image: This is what I'm trying to build.]

Basically, I want to add the purple border for the selected item. I think the ::before pseudo element is the best option here?

I've tried this, but it's not very good at all and it sits right next to the text rather than on the edge of the screen:

```css
#serverList {
  li::before {
    content: 'a';
    height: 5em;
    width: 1em;
    color: blue;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

[image: (this is the result)]

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just set the border color of the li?

Comment: @epascarello because the edges of the purple indicator are rounded - afaik it's not possible with a simple border, but maybe it is :)

Comment: Position it absolutely

Comment: We really need html and css to do this justice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following? You can use a wrapper and add your content inside of a span which is centered.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 40px;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}

.wrapper:hover::before {
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>This is a text</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>This is a second text</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>This is another</span>
</div>
```

**EDIT #1**

If you want to retain the state:

```js
$( ".wrapper" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
       $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px grey;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}

.wrapper.active::before {
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Click here</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Click here 2</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Click here 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Do you know how I could toggle the visibility of the indicator? Like with Vue, or React? I'm not sure how to set the ::before's visibility dynamically.

Comment: If instead of hover you want it to be fixed, you can just add a class to the element you clicked. e.g. (`class=active`)

Comment: You would need javascript for that and add some event listeners. I will update my answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to add position relative to father element:

```
 #serverList li{
    position: relative;
  }
```

Then, let's work in children element(::before)

```
 #serverList li::before{
    content: '';  /* is not necesary any info here */
    height: 5em;
    width: 1em;
    color: blue;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute; /* this is absolute to the father element*/
    left: 0; /* we want this in the point 0 of our father element*/
   }
```

You can play with properties top, left, right, bottom and the position absolute.